# Border around table even though there is no border set

Tags: html, border

http://www.welivetech.net/showthread.php?tid=62

If you look closely, under "test" the thread title you will see a black border. <s>This can also be found to the left of the avatar.</s>

Any ideas? I've tried to fix it to no avail.

Browser: Chrome (latest) on Windows 7 and CentOS.

Comment: have you set your margin and padding to zero? if it doesn't work, try setting the margin-top and margin-left of the avatar container to -1px :)

Comment: Which browser? Which OS? I'm not seeing it on Chrome / OS X.

Comment: @stefan Didn't work. Hmm. Blowski, edited question, thanks!

Comment: This border is set in `.tborder` class : `border: 1px solid 
black;`

Comment: @samsamX But I set border-style to none !important; so why would it ignore it?! Thanks anyway.

Comment: I can't find your `border-style:none !important;` anywhere.

Comment: Why is it coded as tables - this could and should use a CSS layout. Anyway, use Firebug to turn styles on and off until you isolate the issue. Then set the necessary style.

Comment: @Steve on an unrelated note, if you want to make the lowest avatar to display in the corner of the td, use "display: block" on the td. You'll get it to look similar to the other, shorter posts.

Comment: @Blowski How can I contact you to get more information on how to do this? And it is because MyBB is by default that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a border it is the padding of the td inside `<table id="post_120" .../>` add a `cellpadding="0"` attribute to that table and the border will disapear.